# Python Graph Library

Tags: python, graph

I'm writing a python application that will make heavy use of a graph data structure. Nothing horribly complex, but I'm thinking some sort of graph/graph-algorithms library would help me out. I've googled around, but I don't find anything that particularly leaps out at me.

Anyone have any good recommendations?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

There are two excellent choices:

[NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/)

and

[igraph](http://igraph.org/)

I like NetworkX, but I read good things about igraph as well.  I routinely use NetworkX with graphs with 1 million nodes with no problem (it's about double the overhead of a dict of size V + E)

If you want a feature comparison, see this from the Networkx-discuss list

[Feature comparison thread](http://groups.google.com/group/networkx-discuss/t/7597ca97abbb3f90?hl=en)

Comment: In particular, what I like about Networkx.... it's mostly in python, easy to edit and understand the source code, and it feels mostly "pythonic".

Comment: I was wondering, have you used it with a* or similar algorithms?

Comment: I just evaluated both. `networkx` is installable via `pip`, whereas `igraph` is not. This makes `igraph` harder to use as dependencies in your `setup.py` files.

Comment: As an update for 2013, I'm going with networkx just b/c it has a github and looks most up to date of all the options in this answer and the others

Comment: @GreggLind I am using Networkx but I can see in my profiler that getting edges from large graph consumes a lot of time. Are there any guidelines or some documentation for better performance? It would be really helpful.

Comment: igraph also has a github: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph

Comment: igraph can be installed via pip: pip install python-igraph

Comment: I recently used NetworkX for a project, I had lines in a text file that referenced other lines, etc and I need to be able to detect circular references and walk the graph in a 'directed' fashion.  NetworkX worked PERFECTLY for this.  It was fast and easy to use.  It has the "is acyclic graph" function to test if the graph isn't circular.  Cheers!

Answer (score 120):

I would like to plug my own graph python library: [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de).

It is very fast, since it is implemented in C++ with the Boost Graph Library, and it contains lots of algorithms and extensive documentation.

Comment: +1 For graph-tool. We've been using it in our lab. It is really fast compared to other python libraries. Besides, drawing and displaying graph is pretty awesome in graph-tool. Takes a lot of time to compile though!

Comment: I think it would better to give readers a link for comparing the performance of those graph libraries: http://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library
Hello, I wanna give graph-tool a try and I find the instruction to install it as in the above link. However I'm a windows user and of course I don't want to switch to Linux just to use this pack. Is it any way to use this library in Windows using pre-built, easy-to-install method?
(Of course they offered the method to compile this library by myself but this seems to elaborate too much).

Comment: @Tiago Peixoto:  I am keen to try and use the graph-tool library, I have one question, How can I use it with pyQt, basically I am in need of a pyton graph library that allows me to create interactive graphs on a Qt Qgraphicsscene/Qgraphicsview. I noticed that graph-tool can create static graphs, pngs etc using cairo, do you know if its possible to use your library with QgraphicsScene? if so how?

Many thanks

Comment: @user595985 I'm afraid not. Graph-tool uses GTK+/cairo, and hence cannot be easily integrated with Qt. However it does include a ready-to-use GTK+ widget for drawing interactive graphs.

Comment: No windows support unfortunately :(

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto This looks so so promising but can't use it on windows. I am stuck with NetworkX, finding it too slow.

Comment: So embarrassing that such a well-praised tool has no port for Windows user... I find there are too much hassle to build and install on Windows (not to mention there's very high chance that the build will fail).

Comment: Looks great from the documentation. Why doesn't `pip install graph-tool` work?

Comment: @ColonelPanic This is a FAQ, see https://graph-tool.skewed.de/download:  "The short answer is that it can't be done, since graph-tool depends crucially on some (excellent) C++ libraries such as Boost, which are not installable via pip."

Comment: I would love to use it but the GPL license does not allow me to use it :(

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto Hi, I would be delighted if you could help out with this post, very much in unknown territories here :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944901/basic-questions-about-nested-blockmodel-in-graph-tool

Comment: @EdisonGustavoMuenz of course the GPL license allows you to use it... You can even make modifications and distribute those!

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto how does it compares against http://snap.stanford.edu/ringo/ in terms of speed ? They seem promising for speed and multicore processing

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto Can we import planar graphs from shapefiles in graph-tool? I couldn't find anything in the documents so I guess no, but I thought it might be worth it asking the developers.

Comment: @DuccioA Appending to this comment is not the proper way to ask such questions. Please use the mailing list instead: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/mailing

Comment: Not really available on Windows (unless you want to use Google Colab which is not user friendly), and its primary emphasis is network science rather than graph theory. I would call it mostly a network science library, but the flows additions are nice (they are much more commonly used in operations research/graph theory, than in NetSci), wished min-cost-max-flow algos were implemented. Sometimes the visualizations are lovely, as Cairo can do a prettier job, but sometimes (like in igraph) it's too much effort to try to make nodes not overlap in the case of a large graph.

Comment: This is incorrect. As described in the documentation, it's possible to use graph-tool on windows using the WSL: https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions#windows

Answer (score 33):

Have you looked at [python-graph](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/)?  I haven't used it myself, but the project page looks promising.

Answer (score 12):

Also, you might want to take a look at [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Boost Graph Library - Python Bindings](http://www.osl.iu.edu/~dgregor/bgl-python/).

Comment: Nice one dehmann, I went for that first (being a C++ programmer by trade and absolutely loving boost), but this scares me:

BGL-Python bindings are no longer being maintained <a top of page>

Comment: Look at graph-tool instead, it's bgl based and active.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [this page on implementing graphs in python](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/).

You could also take a look at [pygraphlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygraphlib/) on sourceforge.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the most luck with pydot. Some of the others are hard to install and configure on different platforms like Win 7.

http://code.google.com/p/pydot/

Answer (score 1):

I second zweiterlinde's suggestion to use python-graph.  I've used it as the basis of a graph-based research project that I'm working on.  The library is well written, stable, and has a good interface.  The authors are also quick to respond to inquiries and reports.