# Graph layout and rearrangement

Tags: c#, java, python, layout, graph

I'm trying to do a semi-automated graph layout program. After reading the input, the program should generate a graph (with a specified layout). The tricky part is that the user should be able to choose a subset of the nodes and rearrange those with another algorithm (while saving the rest in their original position). I've went through graphviz and while this option is possible it is very limited (using "pin" only with the 'neato' and 'fdp' algorithms... i would prefer my graph to be oriented)

another requirement would be the price.. I've seen that yworks can do what i need but its paid for...

at this point I'll take any language I can get thanx

currently I'm trying out graphsharp but the documentation is very poor

Comment: yworks is paid for? Have you  tried yEd from the same people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For python see [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library)
- For java see [ansers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)

If you're happy with semi-automated graph layout, then what you might do is the following (which I did in the past):

- download [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) (also from yworks)
- save a graph and look at the file: its XML, and the format is not too complex
- write some code that save your graph into an XML file compatible with yEd
- open your file form yEd, and use built-in layout algorithms
- save again your file from yEd

I hope this helps.