# Undirected Graph Reordering the Vertices

Tags: python, graph, numpy

Given an adjacency matrix and a new ordering of vertices how can we permute the graph in python? Is there any library for this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Graph Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library)

Answer (score 3):

You can just construct the new adjacency matrix by hand. `old` is the old adjacency matrix, and `perm` is a vector that stores the old name for each new vertex, that is, if vertex `j` is moved to vertex `i` then `perm[i] == j`.

```
import numpy as np

def rearrange(old, perm):
    n = old.shape[0]
    new = np.zeros_like(old)

    for x in xrange(n):
        for y in xrange(x+1): # only need to traverse half the matrix
            # the matrix is symmetric (because of undirectedness)
            new[y, x] = new[x, y] = old[perm[x], perm[y]]
    return new
```

(Note that I'm assuming you're are storing your adjacency matrix as a dense matrix in an `n`×`n` numpy array. Also, for Python 3.x, `xrange` should be `range`.)