# input networkx graph into zss algorithm (tree edit distance)

Tags: python, graph, tree, distance, networkx

I want to compute the Zhang-Shasha tree-edit distance between 2 trees (`zss` library). However, my trees are in the form of `networkx` graphs (they actually represent DOM html trees). The example in the zss [documentation](https://github.com/timtadh/zhang-shasha) shows how to create a tree by hand:

```
from zss import *
A = (
    Node("f")
        .addkid(Node("a")
            .addkid(Node("h"))
            .addkid(Node("c")
                .addkid(Node("l"))))
        .addkid(Node("e"))
    )
zss.simple_distance(A, A) # [0.0]
```

Which would be the same tree as:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('f', 'a'), ('a', 'h'), ('a', 'c'), ('c', 'l'), ('f', 'e')])
```

so I would like to convert tree objects of networkx class into a `zss` Node object, then compute the edit distance between 2 trees.

Thanks

*(and do not hesitate to tell me if you think this is a XY problem)*

Comment: Seems to me like depth first [traversal](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dfs_tree` can definitely help:

```
import zss
import networkx as nx

G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('f', 'a'), ('a', 'h'), ('a', 'c'), ('c', 'l'), ('f', 'e')])
T = nx.dfs_tree(G, source='f')
nodes_dict = {}
for edge in T.edges():
    if edge[0] not in nodes_dict:
        nodes_dict[edge[0]] = zss.Node(edge[0])
    if edge[1] not in nodes_dict:
        nodes_dict[edge[1]] = zss.Node(edge[1])
    nodes_dict[edge[0]].addkid(nodes_dict[edge[1]])

print(zss.simple_distance(nodes_dict['f'], nodes_dict['f'])) # 0.0
```

In case we don't know which node is G's root node, but know we have a valid tree, we can get the source node by calling:

```
source = [n for (n, d) in G.in_degree() if d == 0][0]
T = nx.dfs_tree(G, source=source)
```

Since the root is the only node with no incoming nodes, that should work.

Comment: thanks, you supply the `source` argument as the top node, i guess? How would I automatize this in a function, i mean could I initialize it as `T = nx.dfs_tree(G, source=list(G.nodes)[0])`, right?

Comment: That would work, as well as simply omitting the source argument and calling `nx.dfs_tree(G)`. However, it assumes G has a specific node ordering, which is true in the above example, but depends on the way we build it. Added an edit to handle this step in the answer.