# Which is the fastest graph representation of Wikipedia out there?

Tags: algorithm, api, graph, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am working on this project where I need to run some graph algorithms on a graph representing English Wikipedia articles. This would need to be in real time

I have tried

- [WikiMapUW](http://code.google.com/p/wiki-map-uw-cse/) which has only a PHP interface
- [WikipediaLinkGraph](http://blog.alwaysmovefast.com/wikipedias-link-graph) which is not as fast as the previous one but has a Python interface

Was wondering if there are some obvious fast Java / Python APIs available that I have missed and are better ?

Comment: What have you tried? These look promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library

Comment: @NoBugs sorry about that. I have edited the question to include what I have tried.

Comment: Is the implication that a vertex in this graph is an article, and a directed edge is a hyperlink between articles?  It is fairly easy to run the XML dump through an XML parser and then search each article body for the regex `\[(.*)\]` to find links.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling It is a lot of data and placing it in memory would not be ideal. Ideally, it would require a database and some caching implementations to give good speed / low memory usage.

Comment: The graph itself will fit in memory easily, it would be way less than a gig.  The entire xml dump is only 30gig.  A simple in-memory uncached representation will be far faster than any database.

Comment: Btw the topic has been discussed at length at http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/analytics/2013-December/thread.html#1368