# How to represent graphs with IPython

Tags: python, graph, ipython, networkx

Recently I discovered `IPython notebook` which is a powerful tool. As an IT student, I was looking for a way to represent graphs in Python. For example, I would like to know if there's a library (like `numpy` or `matplotlib` ?) which can draw from this

```
{ "1" : ["3", "2"],
  "2" : ["4"],
  "3" : ["6"],
  "4" : ["6"],
  "5" : ["7", "8"],
  "6" : [],
  "7" : [],
  "8" : []
}
```

something like this :

[image: (source : developpez.com)]

Is there something like this ?

Comment: Duplicate ? I'm testing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472530/representing-graphs-data-structure-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) and, if you need to render the graph in ipython notebook, [nxpd](https://github.com/chebee7i/nxpd)

```
import networkx as nx
from nxpd import draw
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.graph['dpi'] = 120
G.add_nodes_from(range(1,9))
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,6),(4,5),(4,6),(5,7),(5,8)])
draw(G, show='ipynb')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was what i was looking for. I have just a little issue about valued graphs. Should i print the valuation manually or is there a parameter ? I looked for it but didn't found in the library `nxpd`

Comment: `nxpd` can be installed with `pip install nxpd`

Comment: The above example gives `AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'number_of_selfloops'` with NetworkX 3.2 and nxpd 0.2.0.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [pygraphviz](http://pygraphviz.github.io/):

```
import pygraphviz

G = pygraphviz.AGraph(directed=True)
G.add_nodes_from(range(1,9))
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,6),(4,5),(4,6),(5,7),(5,8)])
G.layout()
G.draw('graph.png')
```

Then in a markdown block:

```
![graph](graph.png)
```

Which renders to:

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

There's already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29785948/857390) using `networkx` and `nxpd`, however `networkx` on its own can plot directly via `matplotlib` (so you don't need `nxpd`):

```py
import networkx as nx

%matplotlib inline

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(range(1, 9))
g.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8)])

nx.draw_planar(g, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

See the [`networkx` documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) for more layout algorithms.

Comment: I tried the other answer but it seemed pip chose incompatible versions of the two packages. This answers saved me from figuring that out

Answer (score 0):

```
import graphviz

source = '''
digraph structs { 
  1 -> 3;
  1 -> 2;
  2 -> 4;
  3 -> 6;
  4 -> 6;
  4 -> 5;  
  5 -> 7;
  5 -> 8;
}
'''

dot = graphviz.Source(source6)

# Render the Graph
dot
```