# How to represent networkx graphs with edge weight using nxpd like outptut

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Recently I asked the question [How to represent graphs with ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774105/representating-graphs-with-ipython). The answer was exactly what i was looking for, but today i'm looking for a way to show the edge valuation on the final picture.

The edge valuation is added like this :

```
import networkx as nx
from nxpd import draw # If another library do the same or nearly the same
                      # output of nxpd and answer to the question, that's
                      # not an issue
import random

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2])
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=random.randint(1, 10))

draw(G, show='ipynb')
```

And the result is here.

[image: Result provided by ipython notebook]

I read the `help` of `nxpd.draw` (didn't see any web documentation), but i didn't find anything.
Is there a way to print the edge value ?

**EDIT** : also, if there's a way to give a formating function, this could be good. For example :

```
def edge_formater(graph, edge):
    return "My edge %s" % graph.get_edge_value(edge[0], edge[1], "weight")
```

**EDIT2** : If there's another library than nxpd doing nearly the same output, it's not an issue

**EDIT3** : has to work with `nx.{Graph|DiGraph|MultiGraph|MultiDiGraph}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/chebee7i/nxpd/blob/master/nxpd/nx_pydot.py) `nxpd.draw` (function `draw_pydot`) calls `to_pydot` which filters the graph attributes like:

```
if attr_type == 'edge':
    accepted = pydot.EDGE_ATTRIBUTES
elif attr_type == 'graph':
    accepted = pydot.GRAPH_ATTRIBUTES
elif attr_type == 'node':
    accepted = pydot.NODE_ATTRIBUTES
else:
    raise Exception("Invalid attr_type.")

d = dict( [(k,v) for (k,v) in attrs.items() if k in accepted] )
```

If you look up [`pydot`](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/master/pydot.py) you find the `pydot.EDGE_ATTRIBUTES` which contains valid Graphviz-attributes. The `weight` strictly refers to edge-weight by Graphviz if I recall, and `label` is probably the attribute you need. Try:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2])
weight=random.randint(1, 10)
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=weight, label=str(weight))
```

---

Note that I haven't been able to test if this works, just downvote if it doesn't.