# converting list to graph?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, graph

Suppose I have a 2D list of booleans such as:

```
[[False, True , False],
 [True, False, False]]
```

Would it be possible to convert this into a graph such that all the adjacent values of the list are connected to each other?  Adjacency meaning just another value either directly next to, above/under, or one diagonal space away from each other. I'm working on a problem that I think would be easier to accomplish with a graph but my input is a list and I was curious if there was a way of doing that?

Comment: Be more precise (if adjacency in a grid is the characteristic, what does true/false mean? what kind of adjacency = how many neighbors?)!

Comment: @sascha sorry about that, the true false values were irrelevant it was just a random example. I just meant two things next, above/under, or diagonal from one another

Comment: Sure that's possible. It's not even hard. Where is the problem? Implement a ```get_neighbor(x,y)``` function and iterate over all nodes, adding edges to the neighbors. Not sure, what kind of graph you want. Which library, directed/undirected and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by 'convert into a graph'?

One possibility is for you to create a structure for representing the graph. I suggest you read the top answer to this question: [Representing graphs (data structure) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472530/representing-graphs-data-structure-in-python)

Then, you create the proper connections and create the graph.

This code assumes all sublists are of equal length and graph is undirected.

```
def getConnections(input_list):
    connections = []
    directions = [(-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1),(1,0)]
    for i in range(0,len(input_list)):
        for j in range(0,len(input_list[0])):
            for x,y in directions:
                if (i+y >= 0 and i+y < len(input_list) and j+x >= 0 and j+x < len(input_list))
                    pair = (input_list[i][j], input_list[i+y][j+x])
                    connections.append(pair)
    return connections

myList = [[False, True , False], [True, False, False]]
connections = getConnections(myList)
myGraph = new Graph(connections, directed = false)
```

Comment: thanks! that link was exactly what I was looking for. I'm primarily a C++ programmer so I wasn't really sure how to ask the question until i read your response. much appreciated.