# Counting all connected nodes in graph

Tags: python, graph

I have a >10k list of (unordered) pairs of numbers. I'd like to classify them into sets of connected pairs either directly or indirectly. I think this corresponds to undirected graph. I'm using python, and tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472530/representing-graphs-data-structure-in-python) to represent this structure.

In order to know all the numbers connected to `i`,
I can examine whether there is a path from `i` to `j` for all `j` in the list except `i`. However, with this implementation, the computation time gets too long for the size of list I'm dealing with. Is there a more efficient way to do this? (Or is there an already established python libraries?)

Comment: Are you trying to find the connected components of a graph?

Comment: @jme Yes, that sounds like what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds as though you are interested in computing the connected components of a graph. I would suggest looking into the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) package and its [tools for computing components](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/algorithms.component.html).

For example, suppose our data is a list of pairs of numbers, each pair representing an edge in the graph:

```
pairs = [
    (1, 2),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 5),
    (2, 5),
    (7, 9),
    (9, 10),
    (8, 7)
]
```

In the graph represented by these edges, there is a path between any pair of nodes in the set `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, and there is also a path between any pair of nodes in `{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`. But there is no path, say, from `5` to `7`. This is to say that there are two connected components in the graph.

To discover these components, we first import `networkx` and create a graph:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> graph = nx.from_edgelist(pairs)
```

Computing the components is as simple as

```
>>> list(nx.connected_components(graph))
>>> [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]
```

`nx.connected_components` is a generator, and so here we converted the result into a list in order to show all of the connected components.

We can also find the connected component containing a given node:

```
>>> nx.node_connected_component(graph, 3)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

We can also quickly count the number of connected components:

```
>>> nx.number_connected_components(graph)
2
```

Comment: Yes, this was what was looking for. Thanks for detailed answer!

Comment: Connected components is also available in scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html. I don't know which implementation is faster, but it may avoid an additional dependency in your projects.

Comment: The second link is broken