# Representing Graph with Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am receiving data in the following format:

```
tail head
P01106  Q09472
P01106  Q13309
P62136  Q13616
P11831  P18146
P13569  P20823
P20823  P01100
...
```

Is there a good way to format this data as a graph with a numpy array? I am hoping to compute PageRank using this graph.

So far I have

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('wnt_edges.txt', skip_header=1, dtype=str)
```

I was thinking about using the graph data structure from [Representing graphs (data structure) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472530/representing-graphs-data-structure-in-python) but it didn't seem to make sense in this case since I'll be doing matrix multiplication.

Comment: Have you considered using `networkx`? You can easily convert your array into an edge list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid reinventing the wheel you should use networkx as suggested in comments and other answers.

If, for educational purposes, you *want to* reinvent the wheel you can create an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). The [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) can be computed from that matrix:

> The PageRank values are the entries of the dominant right eigenvector of the modified adjacency matrix.

Since each row/column of the adjacency matrix represents a node, you will need to enumerate the nodes so each node is represented by a unique number starting from 0.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['P01106', 'Q09472'],
                 ['P01106', 'Q13309'],
                 ['P62136', 'Q13616'],
                 ['P11831', 'P18146'],
                 ['P13569', 'P20823'],
                 ['P20823', 'P01100']])


nodes = np.unique(data)  # mapping node name --> index
noidx = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(nodes)}  # mapping node index --> name

n = nodes.size  # number of nodes

numdata = np.vectorize(noidx.get)(data)  # replace node id by node index

A = np.zeros((n, n))
for tail, head in numdata:
    A[tail, head] = 1
    #A[head, tail] = 1  # add this line for undirected graph
```

This results in the following graph representation `A`:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

A 1 in row 5, column 0 for example means that there is an edge from node 5 to node 0, which corresponds to `'P20823'` --> `'P01100'`. Use the `nodes` array to look up node names from indices:

```
print(nodes)
['P01100' 'P01106' 'P11831' 'P13569' 'P18146' 'P20823' 'P62136' 'Q09472'
 'Q13309' 'Q13616']
```

If there are many nodes and few connections it's better to use a [`sparse matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) for `A`. But first try to stay with a dense matrix and only bother to switch to sparse of you have memory or performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx
#make the graph 
G = nx.Graph([e for e in data])
#compute the pagerank 
nx.pagerank(G)
# output:
# {'P01100': 0.0770275315329843,  'P01106': 0.14594493693403143, 
# 'P11831': 0.1,  'P13569': 0.0770275315329843,  'P18146': 0.1, 
# 'P20823': 0.1459449369340315,  'P62136': 0.1,  'Q09472':
# 0.07702753153298428,  'Q13309': 0.07702753153298428,  'Q13616': 0.1}
```

That's all it takes. [pagerank](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank.html) documentation is here.