# graph data structure with complex edge data

Tags: data-structures, graph-algorithm, undirected-graph

I need a graph data structure implementation that stores a graph with vertices and edges, but my edges need to be objects that can store their own data, unlike just the normal adjacency list implementations.

I remember seeing such a representation for this once, but can not find it now.

It kept a list or map of vertexes and a list or map of edges objects. Can anyone point me to a good reference for this?

Comment: So which programming language are you looking into? Python, Java, C++, javascript etc? Unless you're looking for pseudo code

Comment: pseudo code or just diagram is fine. I will be implementing in python but I am fluent in most languages, so an example in C, C++, Go, Rails, Java, Python, etc would be great!

Comment: I think you should look here and tell me if this does/doesnt answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472530/representing-graphs-data-structure-in-python

Comment: I looked at your refrence, and this is not what I am looking for. The original reference I saw was showing a general diagram to store both vertex object list, and a edge list with associated data. I am not interested in a using module or existing library but the actual technique for the structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an `Edge` class with all the data you need and then have an adjency list whose values aren't vertices but `Edge` object (which store from, to vertices).

If you don't want the `Edge` class to have vertices properties, you could put tuples of (`Edge`, vertice) in your adjency list instead.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up creating a python solution storing edge tuple keys normalized for undirected graphs see code at: https://gist.github.com/gerryjenkinslb/40cc77e72ef96e3446955dbfb9f00f80