# Data type for storing subway/public transit stops in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to create an ego graph consisting of a kind of linked list where each public transit stop is linked or has listed the direct connections to it on public transit.

For example, say subway stop 1 is just a normal subway stop on one metro line. The stop 1 data would be the backwards and forwards stops along the subway line. If we consider subway stop 2 where 2 different metro lines/colors arrive/depart, the data associated with stop 2 would be the 4 next stops on both lines.

Should I make a class and pass values that way? Or maybe a linked list would be better? Maybe I could also use a dictionary but I am not sure which direction I should move in, especially if there is a structure that would be easier to add functionality to in the future (why I am leaning towards making a class). Currently, the direction or order of the stops does not matter. I just need to be able to use the data to chart what stops can be reached from the beginning node.

Comment: Are you asking about how to specify the graph (such as how to input it/store it in a file) or how to implement a graph in memory? Since subway systems tend to be sparse (from a graph perspective), adjacency lists make sense for input/storage, and a regular graph (vertices and edges) would probably be fine for in-memory representation, but it depends on how many vertices there are and how you want to traverse the graph. With the information you've provided, there's no particular reason to choose any particular implementation because your needs are very vague.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Representing graphs (data structure) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472530/representing-graphs-data-structure-in-python)

Comment: I have seen networkx and it is promising but the "graph" is a loose way of saying I just want the information organized. I wanted to know if there was a preferred method of representing this type of data that would prevent me from having to change to later

Comment: It entirely depends on your current and future needs. There are many ways to represent graphs, and they all have strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: "implemented using Python dictionary datastructures. The graph adjacency structure is implemented as a Python dictionary of dictionaries" - NetworkX Documentation. It seems as though I had the right idea with dictionaries