# Creating undirected unweighted graph from dictionary containing neighborhood relationship

Tags: python, graph, networkx, network-analysis

I have a Python dictionary that looks like this:

> {'Aitkin': ['Carlton',   'Cass',   'Crow Wing',   'Itasca',
> 'Kanabec',   'Mille Lacs',   'Pine',   'St. Louis'],  'Anoka':
> ['Chisago',   'Hennepin',   'Isanti',   'Ramsey',   'Sherburne',
> 'Washington'],  'Becker': ['Clay',   'Clearwater',   'Hubbard',
> 'Mahnomen',   'Norman',   'Otter Tail',   'Wadena'],  'Beltrami':
> ['Cass',   'Clearwater',   'Hubbard',   'Itasca',   'Koochiching',
> 'Lake of the Woods',   'Marshall',   'Pennington',   'Roseau'],
> 'Benton': ['Mille Lacs', 'Morrison', 'Sherburne', 'Stearns'],  'Big
> Stone': ['Lac qui Parle', 'Stevens', 'Swift', 'Traverse'],  'Blue
> Earth': ['Brown',   'Faribault',   'Le Sueur',   'Martin',
> 'Nicollet',   'Waseca',   'Watonwan'],  'Brown': ['Blue Earth',
> 'Cottonwood',   'Nicollet',   'Redwood',   'Renville',   'Watonwan'],
> 'Carlton': ['Aitkin', 'Pine', 'St. Louis'],  'Carver': ['Hennepin',
> 'McLeod', 'Scott', 'Sibley', 'Wright'],  'Cass': ['Aitkin',
> 'Beltrami',   'Crow Wing',   'Hubbard',   'Itasca',   'Morrison',
> 'Todd',   'Wadena'],  'Chippewa': ['Kandiyohi',   'Lac qui Parle',
> 'Renville',   'Swift',   'Yellow Medicine'],  'Chisago': ['Anoka',
> 'Isanti', 'Kanabec', 'Pine', 'Washington'],  'Clay': ['Becker',
> 'Norman', 'Otter Tail', 'Wilkin'],  'Clearwater': ['Becker',
> 'Beltrami',   'Hubbard',   'Mahnomen',   'Pennington',   'Polk'],
> 'Cook': ['Lake'],  'Cottonwood': ['Brown', 'Jackson', 'Murray',
> 'Nobles', 'Redwood', 'Watonwan'],  'Crow Wing': ['Aitkin', 'Cass',
> 'Mille Lacs', 'Morrison'],  'Dakota': ['Goodhue', 'Hennepin',
> 'Ramsey', 'Rice', 'Scott', 'Washington'],  'Dodge': ['Goodhue',
> 'Mower', 'Olmsted', 'Rice', 'Steele'],  'Douglas': ['Grant', 'Otter
> Tail', 'Pope', 'Stearns', 'Stevens', 'Todd'],  'Faribault': ['Blue
> Earth', 'Freeborn', 'Martin', 'Waseca'],  'Fillmore': ['Houston',
> 'Mower', 'Olmsted', 'Winona'],  'Freeborn': ['Faribault', 'Mower',
> 'Steele', 'Waseca'],  'Goodhue': ['Dakota', 'Dodge', 'Olmsted',
> 'Rice', 'Wabasha'],  'Grant': ['Douglas', 'Otter Tail', 'Pope',
> 'Stevens', 'Traverse', 'Wilkin'],  'Hennepin': ['Anoka',   'Carver',
> 'Dakota',   'Ramsey',   'Scott',   'Sherburne',   'Wright'],
> 'Houston': ['Fillmore', 'Winona'],  'Hubbard': ['Becker', 'Beltrami',
> 'Cass', 'Clearwater', 'Wadena'],  'Isanti': ['Anoka', 'Chisago',
> 'Kanabec', 'Mille Lacs', 'Pine', 'Sherburne'],  'Itasca': ['Aitkin',
> 'Beltrami', 'Cass', 'Koochiching', 'St. Louis'],  'Jackson':
> ['Cottonwood', 'Martin', 'Nobles', 'Watonwan'],  'Kanabec': ['Aitkin',
> 'Chisago', 'Isanti', 'Mille Lacs', 'Pine'],  'Kandiyohi': ['Chippewa',
> 'Meeker', 'Pope', 'Renville', 'Stearns', 'Swift'],  'Kittson':
> ['Marshall', 'Roseau'],  'Koochiching': ['Beltrami', 'Itasca', 'Lake
> of the Woods', 'St. Louis'],  'Lac qui Parle': ['Big Stone',
> 'Chippewa', 'Swift', 'Yellow Medicine'],  'Lake': ['Cook', 'St.
> Louis'],  'Lake of the Woods': ['Beltrami', 'Koochiching', 'Roseau'],
> 'Le Sueur': ['Blue Earth', 'Nicollet', 'Rice', 'Scott', 'Sibley',
> 'Waseca'],  'Lincoln': ['Lyon', 'Pipestone', 'Yellow Medicine'],
> 'Lyon': ['Lincoln', 'Murray', 'Pipestone', 'Redwood', 'Yellow
> Medicine'],  'Mahnomen': ['Becker', 'Clearwater', 'Norman', 'Polk'],
> 'Marshall': ['Beltrami', 'Kittson', 'Pennington', 'Polk', 'Roseau'],
> 'Martin': ['Blue Earth', 'Faribault', 'Jackson', 'Watonwan'],
> 'McLeod': ['Carver', 'Meeker', 'Renville', 'Sibley', 'Wright'],
> 'Meeker': ['Kandiyohi', 'McLeod', 'Renville', 'Stearns', 'Wright'],
> 'Mille Lacs': ['Aitkin',   'Benton',   'Crow Wing',   'Isanti',
> 'Kanabec',   'Morrison',   'Sherburne'],  'Morrison': ['Benton',
> 'Cass', 'Crow Wing', 'Mille Lacs', 'Stearns', 'Todd'],  'Mower':
> ['Dodge', 'Fillmore', 'Freeborn', 'Olmsted', 'Steele'],  'Murray':
> ['Cottonwood', 'Lyon', 'Nobles', 'Pipestone', 'Redwood', 'Rock'],
> 'Nicollet': ['Blue Earth', 'Brown', 'Le Sueur', 'Renville', 'Sibley'],
> 'Nobles': ['Cottonwood', 'Jackson', 'Murray', 'Rock'],  'Norman':
> ['Becker', 'Clay', 'Mahnomen', 'Polk'],  'Olmsted': ['Dodge',
> 'Fillmore', 'Goodhue', 'Mower', 'Wabasha', 'Winona'],  'Otter Tail':
> ['Becker', 'Clay', 'Douglas', 'Grant', 'Wadena', 'Wilkin'],
> 'Pennington': ['Beltrami', 'Clearwater', 'Marshall', 'Polk', 'Red
> Lake'],  'Pine': ['Aitkin', 'Carlton', 'Chisago', 'Isanti',
> 'Kanabec'],  'Pipestone': ['Lincoln', 'Lyon', 'Murray', 'Rock'],
> 'Polk': ['Clearwater',   'Mahnomen',   'Marshall',   'Norman',
> 'Pennington',   'Red Lake'],  'Pope': ['Douglas', 'Grant',
> 'Kandiyohi', 'Stearns', 'Stevens', 'Swift'],  'Ramsey': ['Anoka',
> 'Dakota', 'Hennepin', 'Washington'],  'Red Lake': ['Pennington',
> 'Polk'],  'Redwood': ['Brown',   'Cottonwood',   'Lyon',   'Murray',
> 'Renville',   'Yellow Medicine'],  'Renville': ['Brown',   'Chippewa',
> 'Kandiyohi',   'McLeod',   'Meeker',   'Nicollet',   'Redwood',
> 'Sibley',   'Yellow Medicine'],  'Rice': ['Dakota',   'Dodge',
> 'Goodhue',   'Le Sueur',   'Scott',   'Steele',   'Waseca'],  'Rock':
> ['Murray', 'Nobles', 'Pipestone'],  'Roseau': ['Beltrami', 'Kittson',
> 'Lake of the Woods', 'Marshall'],  'Scott': ['Carver', 'Dakota',
> 'Hennepin', 'Le Sueur', 'Rice', 'Sibley'],  'Sherburne': ['Anoka',
> 'Benton',   'Hennepin',   'Isanti',   'Mille Lacs',   'Stearns',
> 'Wright'],  'Sibley': ['Carver', 'Le Sueur', 'McLeod', 'Nicollet',
> 'Renville', 'Scott'],  'St. Louis': ['Aitkin', 'Carlton', 'Itasca',
> 'Koochiching', 'Lake'],  'Stearns': ['Benton',   'Douglas',
> 'Kandiyohi',   'Meeker',   'Morrison',   'Pope',   'Sherburne',
> 'Todd',   'Wright'],  'Steele': ['Dodge', 'Freeborn', 'Mower', 'Rice',
> 'Waseca'],  'Stevens': ['Big Stone', 'Douglas', 'Grant', 'Pope',
> 'Swift', 'Traverse'],  'Swift': ['Big Stone',   'Chippewa',
> 'Kandiyohi',   'Lac qui Parle',   'Pope',   'Stevens'],  'Todd':
> ['Cass', 'Douglas', 'Morrison', 'Otter Tail', 'Stearns', 'Wadena'],
> 'Traverse': ['Big Stone', 'Grant', 'Stevens', 'Wilkin'],  'Wabasha':
> ['Goodhue', 'Olmsted', 'Winona'],  'Wadena': ['Becker', 'Cass',
> 'Hubbard', 'Otter Tail', 'Todd'],  'Waseca': ['Blue Earth',
> 'Faribault',   'Freeborn',   'Le Sueur',   'Rice',   'Steele'],
> 'Washington': ['Anoka', 'Chisago', 'Dakota', 'Ramsey'],  'Watonwan':
> ['Blue Earth', 'Brown', 'Cottonwood', 'Jackson', 'Martin'],  'Wilkin':
> ['Clay', 'Grant', 'Otter Tail', 'Traverse'],  'Winona': ['Fillmore',
> 'Houston', 'Olmsted', 'Wabasha'],  'Wright': ['Carver', 'Hennepin',
> 'McLeod', 'Meeker', 'Sherburne', 'Stearns'],  'Yellow Medicine':
> ['Chippewa',   'Lac qui Parle',   'Lincoln',   'Lyon',   'Redwood',
> 'Renville']}

The keys in the dictionary represent the nodes, while the values(lists) represent nodes of neighbors of the key. This is an undirected unweighted graph.

Is there some function to implement this in `networkx` or some network analysis or graph-related libraries?

Comment: Can you post the full dictionary or a smaller, self-contained snippet that contains the original graph data?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark thanks for responding. I have added the full dictionary for reference. Thanks!

Comment: I think this might be the one. Let me check. https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_lists.html#networkx.convert.from_dict_of_lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Representing graphs (data structure) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472530/representing-graphs-data-structure-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nx.Graph` constructor -- it will add additional nodes if they don't appear as keys in the original dictionary (`data` represents the dictionary in the original question):

```py
import networkx as nx
graph = nx.Graph(data)
```