# Using Boost Graph Library in Python

Tags: c++, python-2.7, boost, boost-python

Hi I have been looking at graph libraries that will allow me to create interactive graphs on PyQt QgraphicsScene,(kind of like facebook/LinkedIn social graphs) while I have not found many python libraries that work well with Qt/PyQt(fast, with numerous layout algorithms)  I did come across Boost Graph Library(BGL), It is a C++ library I would like to know if/how I can make use of BGL from my python code,

I am thinking I can add nodes and edges to a BGL graph object, then call BGL's draw graph method this, to my understanding will calculate the positions/layout of the nodes and edges and I can translate these to points onto my QgraphicsScene. My first question is how can I call/make use of BGL directly from my Python code,(pointers to examples would be great) 
Secondly is there another C++ library that I can use, that is fast and robust and plays nice with Python?
Note: I am not really familiar with C++, and am running on Windows
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First part of your question is about Python graph library. It is discussed in depth here: [Python Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library)

Second question is about how to draw a graph.

In BGL it corresponds to the concept of "layout algorithms", see chapter 16 here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html.

Other libraries simply hide these layout algorithms and provide you with function similar to `graph_draw` (from graph-tool), see example here http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#creating-and-manipulating-graphs