# Django finding paths between two vertexes in a graph

Tags: python, django, recursion, django-models, logic

This is mostly a logical question, but the context is done in Django.

In our Database we have Vertex and Line Classes, these form a (neural)network, but it is unordered and I can't change it, it's a Legacy Database

```
class Vertex(models.Model)
    code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lines = models.ManyToManyField('Line', through='Vertex_Line')

class Line(models.Model)
    code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Vertex_Line(models.Model)
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vertex = models.ForeignKey(Vertex, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, in the application, the user will be able to visually select **TWO** vertexes (the green circles below)

[image]

The javascript will then send the pk of these two Vertexes to Django, and it has to find the Line classes that satisfy a route between them, in this case, the following 4 red Lines :

[image]

Business Logic:

- A Vertex can have 1-4 Lines related to it
- A Line can have 1-2 Vertexes related to it
- There will only be one possible route between two Vertexes

What I have so far:

- I understand that the answer probably includes recursion
- The path must be found by trying every path from one Vertex untill the other is find, it can't be directly found
- Since there are four and three-way junctions, all the routes being tried must be saved throughout the recursion(unsure of this one)

I know the basic logic is looping through all the lines of each Vertex, and then get the other Vertex of these lines, and keep walking recursively, but I really don't know where to start on this one.

This is as far as I could get, but it probably does not help (views.py) :

```
def findRoute(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    v1 = Vertex.objects.get(pk=data.get('v1_pk'))
    v2 = Vertex.objects.get(pk=data.get('v2_pk'))
    lines = v1.lines.all()
    routes = []
    for line in lines:
        starting_line = line
        #Trying a new route
        this_route_index = len(routes)
        routes[this_route_index] = [starting_line.pk]
        other_vertex = line.vertex__set.all().exclude(pk=v1.pk)
        #There are cases with dead-ends
        if other_vertex.length > 0:
        #Mind block...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you has pointed, this is not a Django/Python related question, but a logical/algorithmic matter.

To find paths between two vertexes in a graph you can use lot of algorithms: [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm), [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search), [Floyd–Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) etc.. You can choose depending on what you need: shortest/minimum path, all paths...

How to implement this in Django? I suggest to don't apply the algorithm over the models itself, since this could be expensive (in term of time, db queries, etc...) specially for large graphs; instead, I'd rather to map the graph in an in-memory data structure and execute the algorithm over it.

You can take a look to this [Networkx](http://networkx.github.io/), which is a very complete (data structure + algorithms) and well documented library; [python-graph](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-graph), which provides a suitable data structure and a whole set of important algorithms (including some of the mentioned above). More options at [Python Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library)

Comment: I personally wanted to do it by relationships as that seemed faster, but Networkx really is amazing and helped with other projects