# Identifying actual branch names of git commits

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

[image]

This is a simple git repository. I have tagged the commits with numbers for easy referencing. The repo has the following branches:

- master: 13 commits (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
- new_branch: 8 commits  (1,2,3,4,5,6,14,15)
- test_branch: 3 commits (1,2,3)
- yet_another_branch: 14 commits (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,16,17)

Commit 5,6 belong to a pull request thus the blue portion with 5,6 is not a branch.

Please note that commit 1,2 are considered as part of all branches, but I want to consider all black colored commits as part of the master. Similarly, for 'test-branch', I want to consider only commit 3 as part of the branch.

```
from git import Repo

git_url = "https://github.com/unimamun/test-repo.git"
repo_dir = "/mnt/hdd/aam/J2_Repos/test-repo/test-repo"

repo = Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir)

# get all commits by branches    
def get_commits(repo, ref_name):
    commits = []
    for commit in repo.iter_commits(rev=ref_name):
        commits.append(commit)
    return commits

print('\nCommits in Branches:')
for ref in repo.references:
    print(ref.name,': ', str(len(get_commits(repo, ref.name))))


print('\nCommits in master:')
commits = list(repo.iter_commits('master'))
commits.reverse()
i = 0
for commit in commits:
    i += 1
    print(i,': ', commit.hexsha)

    # to see parents of the commit 
    #print('Parents: ',commit.parents)
```

From the above code, I have the following output:

```
Commits in Branches:
master :  13
origin/HEAD :  13
origin/master :  13
origin/new_branch :  8
origin/test-branch :  3
origin/yet_another_branch :  14

Commits in master:
1 :  694df9fee2f9c03a33979725e76a484bce1738a0
2 :  c0fe1b76131b7fcb103f171fd93d85cda17b756c
3 :  0199ad335f65d52a2895a678a19e209e1e16a1a7
4 :  dd0903259b0aadbf2d8fb00e566eee014264f7c0
5 :  7ed55c51e2527f47bc6344cd960ff5beb90cc65d
6 :  d10f19c85fbc1c27b7719a2dc64989255697181d
7 :  c41bdfaeae1f801776420ce161ca2555dffc5aad
8 :  56b5d6e1831a477c79e0fd336acc96ca266d5dea
9 :  6305a72d4e257ebe74b10ca538906f1eceb091bf
10 :  4c5d1ebe5f2f8168ee8bf4a969855821d04caf09
11 :  362bc52be00af3fb917196cf27a8ddc0bb8fd4ba
12 :  5a70a46394eb08b4b48f9eb05798048ca7269a9d
13 :  f4a8bdd318b2678191d06616a55df26416a28363
```

I want the following output. So that 'master' is printed for every black dots in the figure and other branch names for non-black color commits (in this case for green colored commit 3, test-branch should be printed)

```
Commits in master:
1 :  694df9fee2f9c03a33979725e76a484bce1738a0 master
2 :  c0fe1b76131b7fcb103f171fd93d85cda17b756c master
3 :  0199ad335f65d52a2895a678a19e209e1e16a1a7 test-branch
4 :  dd0903259b0aadbf2d8fb00e566eee014264f7c0 master
5 :  7ed55c51e2527f47bc6344cd960ff5beb90cc65d master
6 :  d10f19c85fbc1c27b7719a2dc64989255697181d master
7 :  c41bdfaeae1f801776420ce161ca2555dffc5aad master
8 :  56b5d6e1831a477c79e0fd336acc96ca266d5dea master
9 :  6305a72d4e257ebe74b10ca538906f1eceb091bf master
10 :  4c5d1ebe5f2f8168ee8bf4a969855821d04caf09 master
11 :  362bc52be00af3fb917196cf27a8ddc0bb8fd4ba master
12 :  5a70a46394eb08b4b48f9eb05798048ca7269a9d master
13 :  f4a8bdd318b2678191d06616a55df26416a28363 master
```

I need to iterate from commit 1 to 13 and along the way I need to determine which commit belong to which branch. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As you note:

> commit 1,2 are considered as part of all branches

That is, the *set of reachable commits* from any given branch, as determined by starting at the branch tip commit and working backwards through the Directed Acyclic Graph of commits, always includes commits 1 and 2.

> but I want to consider all black colored commits as part of the master [branch]

In that case, start by finding the graph of all commits.  As you probably know, a graph is defined as *G = (V, E)* where *V* is the set of all vertices and *E* is the set of all edges.  Git stores the vertex and edge data together, in a commit: the commit's identity is its hash ID and its edges—outgoing arcs, really, since this is a directed graph—are its parent commit hash IDs.

Next, use the name you wish to designate as the "most important" branch (i.e., `master`) to find the hash ID of its tip commit.  Assign this commit to the master set.  Walk the reachable portion of the graph, starting from this commit, adding each commit to the set of commits in `master`.

Now, for each remaining branch—in some order, and this order will determine your results in many cases, so you may wish to use a topological sort—start at the tip of the branch and walk the reachable portion of the graph:

- For any commit that is already assigned to some branch, ignore it—and you can immediately stop walking the graph at this point since all its predecessors will, by definition, be assigned to some branch.
- The set of commits you reached during this walk is the set of commits you wish to claim "belong to" this branch.

There are multiple ways to implement this, including walking a subgraph determined by set-subtraction: simply subtract each branch's subgraph from the original *G*.

If it's more convenient—it may well be, since you won't have to find *G*—you can do this in the other direction: start with `master` and find reachable commits that are not in some set that's initially empty.  Add each commit to the set, while listing them as "in master".  Then iterate through the remaining branches: if a commit is in the set-so-far it has already been claimed, else it gets claimed by this branch.  The problem with working this way is that you might pick some branch (`feature-X`) that contains all commits that are contained by some other branch (`develop`) before picking the smaller branch (`develop`): you cannot do a topological sort without the full graph.

Once you have done this for all branch tips, you have now assigned each reachable-from-a-branch-tip commit to a single branch (instead of, as Git does, assigning it to *every* branch from which it is reachable).

Note that there may exist commits in the Git graph that are not reachable from any branch tip (e.g., are reachable from a tag but not from a branch).  If you dig into the internals of Git, you can find commits that are reachable only from *reflog* entries, or even some that are completely unreachable, discoverable only by iterating through the entire object key-value database.  The latter is essentially what `git gc` does: walk the database to find all objects, then do a mark-and-sweep garbage collection operation, much like Lisp would do, retaining reachable objects and discarding the unreachable ones.

Comment: I was expecting, there would be an easier way to find the branch[es] of a commit. This seems rather complicated :(
Thanks a lot for your detail reply.

Comment: It is fundamentally tricky precisely *because* commits are on multiple branches. It often makes more sense to list each commit according to the *set of branches that reach it*, i.e., `git branch --contains <commit>`'s output.

Comment: By the way, you can pull in some impressively complete graph manipulator libraries in Python. Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask, but see the answers to the closed question https://stackoverflow.com/q/606516/1256452

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try the "`--first-parent`" option:

```
git log --oneline --first-parent master
```

Mathematically speaking, this is a graph, which makes that at merge point, no branch is supposed to be "more important" than the other one. But in the facts, the problem always raises and when performing a "merge" operation, one actually "brings" an external branch into the current one. This current branch is therefore stated as the first one inside the commit object.

If you try this on the master branch of a large project such as the linux kernel, you'll mainly fall on merge points, with only a few direct changesets on the branch.

And if this is precisely what you want to know about, you can additionally specify "`--no-merges`" to explicitly exclude merge points.

```
git --oneline --first-parent --no-merges master
```

This, for instance, would exclude points **4** and **7** from your graph.

Finally, to restrict a search to commits that only belongs to a specific branch and that are not inherited from the master one, use the "`..`" operator:

```
git log master..yourbranch
```

… would only show commits that are reachable from "yourbranch" but NOT from "master".

Comment: Thanks for the clues. It feels, it would be easier to solve the problem with git console commands than gitpython. 

Btw. **git log master..origin/test-branch** returns no commits as test-branch is merged with the master thus a part of it. But I can find the difference with simple set operations. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Indeed, this last command should return an empty commit set, as the branch was merged at step 4, which makes all its commits reachable from master branch. What you could be interested to, now, is using a git client, either graphical or text-based (such as **tig**) which clearly materializes branches and makes them much easier to browse.