# I need a bar graph with three variables at the same time

Tags: python, csv, graph

I need a bar graph with three columns at the y axis: rating_standard, rating_rapid, rating_blitz.

I attach a graph similar to my request.

```
df_7 = df3[(df3['fide_id'] == 14109336)]
```

**df_7**

| fide_id | year | month | rating_standard | rating_rapid | rating_blitz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 146116 | 2015 | 1 | 2530.0 | 2599.0 | 2540.0 |
| 146116 | 2015 | 2 | 2530.0 | 2530.0 | 2530.0 |
| ..... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 146116 | 2021 | 3 | 2546.0 | 2546.0 | 2546.0 |
| 146116 | 2021 | 4 | 2546.0 | 2521.0 | 2608.0 |

[image: Look this]

Comment: Im not sure I get your question, on the x-axis you mean[bottom]?? You could try a library. also, check this out, I think its python/graph related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library

Comment: Please try using plotly https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/, this tutorial should explain how to do what you want

Comment: No it cannot be. It is often did with sex. I have three dfifferent colomns not one with two values.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your df_7 is a pandas DataFrame, there are two ways to do this:

**easiest way**:

```py
df_7.plot(kind='bar',x='month',y=['rating_standard','rating_rapid','rating_blitz'])
```

**another way using `seaborn`**, you can first change the way the data is stored in it like this:

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars=['month'], 
        value_vars=['rating_standard','rating_rapid','rating_blitz'], 
        var_name='rating',
        value_name='value', 
        )
```

it will make the table as:

```
    month   rating      value
0   1   rating_standard 2530.0
1   2   rating_standard 2530.0
2   3   rating_standard 2546.0
3   4   rating_standard 2546.0
4   1   rating_rapid    2599.0
```

where those rating columns are now a variable, i.e. each row in the original table now corresponds to 3 rows in the new table. Then you can use seaborn as the following:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=df, x='month', y='value', hue='rating')
```

[image: sample output]

let me know if you want to be exactly like the image you shared, like the month names, colors, etc. then we can make some changes.